# How do I search for an entity in Google App engine by user?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datamodel

I am attempting to lookup a user entity that is related to the current user, and I do not seem to be able to find the user after they get stored in the database.

When I am creating the user for the first time, the call I make looks like the following:

```
newPlayer = model.Player(parent=model.user_key(), user=users.GetCurrentUser(), publicName = nickname)
newPlayer.put()
```

Where model.Player is the element I am trying to lookup, and model.user_key() gets a global ancestor user key.

When I go to look them up, I do the following:

```
model.Player.all().filter('user =', usr).ancestor(user_key()).fetch(1)
```

The model Player class looks like this:

```
class Player(db.Model):
    user = db.UserProperty
    publicName = db.StringProperty()
```

This returns an empty list every time.  What am I doing wrong here?  I am starting to question determinism at this point...

Comment: I just realized - I should mention, I am testing locally

Comment: As far as I know, you should do: model.Player( __parent__ =model.user_key(),...

Comment: @fceruti yeah - fixed that just now.  Still doesn't seem to be working.  You were correct though - I had missed that.  Thanks.

Comment: @fceruti model class added in - thanks for looking at it :)

Comment: one last question, player and user is 1:1 or 1:n ?

Comment: The user is the standard google user object - and they are 1:1 as long as the user is registered.

Comment: Just a comment - you probably don't want to make everything the child of a single global entity; this will put all Player objects into a single entity group, limiting the total write rate _across all Players_ to about one write per second.

Comment: @bdonlan Thanks - I am just trying to get something working right now, that is why I am doing that.  I was going to change that to something else once I could actually look up the players.

Comment: @aperkins, since keys are immutable, it's difficult to migrate data like you say later on, so get this fixed before you have too much data to deal with :)

Comment: Oh yeah - this is not anywhere near ready for people to look at - thanks :)  It is next on the list, actually.  :)

Comment: Using a single parent entity for all the User records in your datastore is a really, really bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User is not a class in datastore, so you can't make player a child of it. This should work:

```
newPlayer = model.Player(user=users.get_current_user(), publicName='john')
newPlayer.put()

usr = users.get_current_user()
john = model.Player.all().filter('user =', usr).fetch(1)
print john.nickname
>> 'john'
```

Note: is **get_current_user()** not **GetCurrentUser()** [source](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/functions.html#get_current_user)

Comment: GetCurrentUser() is an alias for get_current_user() in the users.py file - it came up before the get_current_users in my auto-complete.  That said, I am still not getting any results that make sense for me - I am trying exactly what you showed there, and nothing is happening.

Comment: Also, fetch returns a list of the results - so you would need model.Player.all().filter('user =', usr).fetch(1)
[0] - that said, I am still getting an empty list.  I am wondering if one is actually able to search using users in the 2.5 python environment...

Comment: could you change the user field to user = db.UserProperty __()__

Comment: Did that - nothing changed.  :(

Comment: Wait - no, that fixed it.  I just tried it again, remembered to save (:P) and it worked!  THANK YOU SO MUCH!  I really appreciate it.